# Javascript and jQuery for a grey button to turn red

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-events

I am developing an application where I have the next JS code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>jQuery Hover Effect</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src="/var/www/JSPROBAK/jquery.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").hover(function() {
        $(this).attr("src","/var/www/JSPROBAK/button-hover.png");
            }, function() {
        $(this).attr("src","/var/www/JSPROBAK/button.png");
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<img src="/var/www/JSPROBAK/button.png" alt="My button" class="button" />
</body>
</html>
```

The directory where I have button.png, button-hover.png and jquery.js is the one specified in the code. The code is supposed to turn a gray button (button.png) into a red button (button-hover.png) when putting the mouse over the gray button. The browser initially shows the image of the gray button but doesn't turn red when putting the mouse over it so I am assuming jquery.js is not being loaded correctly, any idea?

Comment: Do you have any errors on the console?  Have you tried debugging to see if the code is being called at all?

Comment: try it with `alert($)` if it's `undefined` => yes jQuery was not loaded.

Comment: No errors on the console. Any idea?

Comment: @Haritz. was it loaded? is the path to jQuery js valid?

Comment: You cannot do it with pure CSS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that you are referencing the server file location not the website relative location. if you are hosting the website from the www dir then I would try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>jQuery Hover Effect</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src="/JSPROBAK/jquery.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").hover(function() {
        $(this).attr("src","/JSPROBAK/button-hover.png");
            }, function() {
        $(this).attr("src","/JSPROBAK/button.png");
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<img src="/JSPROBAK/button.png" alt="My button" class="button" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are referencing the file from the server's physical path, not the virtual one. Try remove `var/www/` from the URLs, and if your HTML-file already resides in `/JSPROBAK/` you can specify the paths as straight out relative paths like `<img src="button.png" />`.

Answer (score 1):

jsFiddle( http://jsfiddle.net/ZWxEg/10/ )

If this code doesn't work for you, then you're not loading jQuery correctly.

-- Edited -- Using hover at gdoron's request :D

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>jQuery Hover Effect</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src="/var/www/JSPROBAK/jquery.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").hover( function ()
    {
         $(this).attr("src","http://www.google.com/logos/2012/sovereignty12_hp.jpg");
    },
    function ()
    {
         $(this).attr("src","http://www.google.com/logos/2012/sundback12-hp.jpg");
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<img src="http://www.google.com/logos/2012/sundback12-hp.jpg" alt="My button" class="button" />
</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: this what `.hover` does for you out of the box!

Comment: @gdoron ah ha! i assumed hover meant the user would need to hover for a second to trigger it.. apparently i was mistaken. thanks!

Comment: Same problem. Any idea why jquery is not being loaded?

Comment: @Haritz where is your jquery file located directory-wise? you could always just link to theirs directly, and not host it on your server.

Answer (score 0):

you won't be able to fade like this, if its just a solid colour you can do it with https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

- otherwise create `<a>` container with position relative (or another element if its not supposed to be clickable)
- inside have 2 absolutely position images, one on top of the other
- the underneath one is the hover and should have a lower z-index set (set z-index on both)
- on the `<a>` hover event fadeOut the one with the highest z-index
- on animation complete swap the z-indexes

Comment: The example is taken from the next site: http://bavotasan.com/2009/a-simple-mouseover-hover-effect-with-jquery/ and its working correctly there. Any other idea?

Comment: that's not a fadeout, if you are simply image swapping you don't need to use jquery at all - instead do it like this: http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/pure-css-image-hover